# Combining two text files

Tags: linux, text-processing

I want to combine two text file in a certain fashion as shown below using Linux terminal:
Rule is that I add two files such that every line of file 2 comes alternatively except for 6 under which no line should come from file 2 and for 7 , 2 line should come under this from file 2

File 1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

File 2:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```

Output:

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
4
d
5
e
6
7
f
g
8
h
9
i
10
j
11
```

Comment: Please add some information what you have tried and where you are stuck. And tell us what are the rules for the combination, I cannot see a simple logic. What is the rule to have `c` in front of `3` ?

Comment: now 7 is before f?

Comment: Yeah..I need to do exactly as above

Comment: I have added the rule that each line from file 2 should come alternatively except for 6 and 7 where no line should come under 6 and 2 line from file 2 should come under 7

Comment: Please stop adding information to the comments. Go back and [edit] your question so that it's easy for people to see what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -e '6!RFile 2' -e '7RFile 2' File\ 1
1
a
2
b
3
c
4
d
5
e
6
7
f
g
8
h
9
i
10
j
11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{Arr[NR]=$0;next}{print;if(Arr[FNR]){print Arr[FNR]}}' file2 file1
1
a
2
b
3
c
4
d
5
6
```

read the file2 and keep the values in Array, then start to read the file1 and print along with the file2 values